# Ropsten faucet not working for me

Tags: mining, testnets

I tried to send test ethers to the main account address created on Ethereum wallet by using the Ropsten faucet (http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/) but did not receive any . My wallet is synced with Ropsten test network.

Any suggestions on how I can get some ethers into my testnet account?

Comment: For me the Thinklair Ropsten Faucet works
try this out https://www.moonborrow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some ethers from the faucet :-

http://ipfs.b9lab.com:8080/ipfs/QmU7Ecw419si7D8gq4tB3qVBraitBGeVrsMESHBMD1DnCb

Or

https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmU7Ecw419si7D8gq4tB3qVBraitBGeVrsMESHBMD1DnCb

Or

http://ipfs.b9lab.com:8080/ipns/faucet.ipns.b9lab.com/

Using this url ,one can receive maximum of 1.5 ethers in a Ropsten testnet account

Comment: It doesn't work, but shows `Error: {}`

Answer (score 12):

Here's a list of a couple worth trying, since some might get some downtime or experience high demand depending on when you try:

- [Thinklair](https://moonborrow.com)
- [MyCrypto Faucet](https://app.mycrypto.com/faucet)
- [Metamask Faucet](https://faucet.metamask.io)
- [Ropsten.be Faucet](https://faucet.ropsten.be)

Some of these allow to donate your testnet ETH, so please do once you're done using it so it doesn't become lost forever!

Comment: Unfortunately, https://faucet.metamask.io/ is not working currently. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AdamHurwitz updated my answer

Comment: Currently none of those are working.. any idea how to get ropsten test ether?

Comment: For me the Thinklair Ropsten Faucet works.
try this https://www.moonborrow.com

Answer (score 1):

When I tried, the faucet mentioned in the question gave 3 ETH every 7 seconds:

http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, it's been down for about 2 weeks, hopefully it comes back up soon.

Comment: @TomHale It's still not working, but I'm hopeful it will come back soon, too. It returns a txHash! But that tx hash doesn't work. Where is it getting these tx hashes? Just making them up!? https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x9b2454fdd299b6e82bdb146855ec4a03a2c71bbff61c87171d38b1ec67adca00

Answer (score -1):

https://faucet.metamask.io/
this worked for me. I accessed it from the buy button after selecting the Ropsten Testnet

Comment: Look at other answers before posting.